# How do in install chempy on Linux using miniconda?

Tags: python, jupyter

Tried to install [chempy](https://github.com/bjodah/chempy) on Linux as described in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/chempy/):

```
conda create -n chempy python=3.9
conda activate chempy
conda install -c bjodah chempy pytest
```

This resulted in the following error message.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - chempy -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.4.*']
```

Switching to python version 3.6 didn't help either, as some packages explicitly demand 3.9 or higher.

System specification:

- Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Miniconda version: 4.10.1
- Python: 3.9

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [chempy conda package](https://anaconda.org/bjodah/chempy) is not complete, nor is the pip [package](https://pypi.org/project/chempy/).
The only way it works seems to be to install dependencies manually from separate sources.

1. Install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), create a separate environment and activate it:

```
conda create -n "chempy" python=3.9
conda activate chempy
```

2. Install dependencies

```
conda install -c anaconda boost
conda install -c conda-forge gsl
conda install -c conda-forge pycvodes
conda install -c conda-forge sundials
```

3. Now you can install chempy:

```
python3 -m pip install chempy[all]
```

4. Test your installation:

```
python3 -m pytest -rs -W \
ignore::chempy.ChemPyDeprecationWarning --pyargs \
chempy > test.out
```

The following tests will fail but chempy works nonetheless:

```
kinetics/tests/test__native.py FF..FFFFFF                                [  3%]
...
util/tests/test_table.py ..FFF                                           [100%]
```

System specification:

- Operating systems: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Debian 10.9 (both 64-Bit-PC)
- Miniconda version: 4.10.1
- Python: 3.9

Note for Windows users:

Not all dependencies are available for Windows, so it's not possible to install chempy on Windows.
I recommend installing it in a virtual machine such as [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) (not tested).